# Table with scrollbar is not created correctly

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I want to create a 20 x 5 table with Tkinter and add a scrollbar. Each element of the table corresponds to an entry widget.

My solution works only partially: The scrollbar is added correctly. But only three columns are shown instead of five, as you can see in the picture below.

[image]

The missing two columns should of course be placed so that they are below the labels.Do any of you see my mistake and know how to fix it to get the desired result:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
Label(root, text = "x").grid(row = 0, column = 0)
Label(root, text = "y").grid(row = 0, column = 1)
Label(root, text = "z").grid(row = 0, column = 2)
Label(root, text = "a").grid(row = 0, column = 3)
Label(root, text = "f(x,y,z;a)").grid(row = 0, column = 4)

container = Frame(root)
canvas = Canvas(container, height = 190)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(container, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
scrollable_frame = Frame(canvas)

scrollable_frame.bind(
    "<Configure>",
    lambda e: canvas.configure(
        scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")
    )
)

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

cells = {}
row, column = 20, 5
for i in range(row):
    for j in range(column):
        b = Entry(scrollable_frame)
        b.grid(row = i + 1  , column = j, sticky = W + E)
        cells[(i, j)] = b

container.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 5)
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The columns are all there, they are just too wide to fit. You can see this by temporarily setting the width of the entry widgets to one or two.

Comment: Is there a way automatically adjust the size/width of the frame (or canvas) depending on the number and size of the columns?